# New data with R and tm when tf-idf is used

Tags: r, tm, tf-idf, text-classification

Using R and tm, I have loaded and cleaned up a bunch of text documents, and made them into a Corpus. After that, I built their DTM using tf-idf, and that I can use for all kind of classification-clustering algorithms. So far, so good.

Now, let's suppose that I have a new document, and try to compute its distance to the documents in the Corpus. Of course, I need to apply to it all the transformations I applied to the original set. But I do not understand how to compute the tf-idf vector of the new document, because tf-idf dependes on the whole set, not on this single document. Adding the new document to the Corpus and recomputing its tf-idf DTM does not work properly: not only it is inefficient, but also every new document would chance the values of the documents already seen, which would in change the results of any clustering-classification algorithm I might have run with them as traininig set.

So, my question is, how can I, using R and tm, compute the tf-idf vector of a new document and use it to compute the new document's distance to every document in the training Corpus without recomputing tf-idf for all documents?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First  you can calculate idf in your training script and save it as R obj.

```
idf = log2(nDocs(dtm)/col_sums(dtm > 0))
```

Then in scoring script you can load this idf and using below logic normalize your scoring dtm

```
for(i in 1:length(dtmscore$i)){dtmscore$v[i] = idf[dtmscore$j[i]] * dtmscore$v[i] }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Where are these functions from? `col_sums` etc?